# 3D "stack of diagrams"

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

A fiber bundle in `U\in \mathbb B` is given by the figure (made in tikzcd)

[image]

I'd like to draw a 3D figure -- an illustration, not an exact mathematical diagram that looks like a stack of triangles like that, possibly with simplified labels. This is why: if `U` is a neighborhood of a point in `R^k`, then UxC is homeomorphic to `\tau^{-1}(U)`, which is the tangent space. But the object I want to discuss is a tangent bundle, which is sort of like stacking many diagrams (with its own `\varphi` homeomorphism) like it.

I don't have a clear visual reference of what this should look like other than "an artistic representation of a pile of these diagrams". Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Rather than posting an image please post some working code for people to start from. Also, you can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: I don't see any triangles. Do you want triangles? Or arrows? How are you drawing the base diagram? You've tagged this `tikz-cd`, so presumably you're using that. The code would be much more helpful than an image of something you aren't trying to draw.

Comment: The syntax at other *exchange sites is

$$ f(\text{this and such}) $$

for display math, but this doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    3Dstack/.style={
        x={(1cm, 0cm)},
        y={(0cm, 1cm)},
        z={(2mm, 5mm)},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3Dstack]
\foreach \z in {6,...,0} {
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \fill[white, opacity=.2] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \node (tau) at (0,0,\z) {$\tau^-1(U)$};
    \node (UxC) [right=of tau] {$U\times \mathbb{C}$};
    \node (U)   [below=of tau] {$U$};
    \draw[->] (tau) -- node[above]{$\varphi_{\z}$} (UxC);
    \draw[->] (tau) -- node[left]{$\tau_{\z}$} (U);
    \draw[->] (UxC) -- node[below right]{$\text{pr}_{\z}$} (U);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wasn't sure which variables need indices, so please check that they are right.

You can change the perspective by adjusting the `z` vector in the `3Dstack` style.

If you don't like the effect of fading out you can remove the `scope` environment with the `overlay` option (including the `\fill` in it's body).

Comment: Very nice :) many compliments. I have voted your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\tau^{-1}(U) \arrow[d, "\tau"'] \arrow[r, "\varphi"] & U\times \mathbb{C} \arrow[ld, "\mathrm{pr}_1"] \\
U & 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```